# "$f^\prime (c) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^\prime (x_n)$" does not imply the continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Question: suppose $f : [a,b] \rightarrow R$ is a differentiable and $c \in [a,b]$. Then show there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $c$, $x_n \not = c$ for all $n$, such that $f^\prime (c) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^\prime (x_n)$. Do note this does not imply that $f^\prime$ is continuous (why?).

Attempt: Let $x_n \in [a,b]$ Then, $f(x_n)$ is differentiable.  Then, $f^\prime (c) = f^\prime(\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f^\prime(x_n)$.

I don't understand why this does not imply continuity because if $f(c)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)$, $f$ is continuous at $c$. Isn't it the case for the derivative function?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I agree that my attempt above assumes that $f^\prime$ is continuous, which might not be true. So, could you give me some hint to solve this problem without using that assumption?

Let $x_n \in [a,b]$. Then, $f(x_n)$ is differentiable. Then, $\lim_{x_n \to c} \frac {f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}=f^\prime (c)$.I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: No, there are functions which are differentiable yet not *continuously* differentiable. Your proof is wrong, in that it starts by assuming the latter (i.., you use that $f'$ is continuous. But it may not be...)

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. This would have to be true for *every* such sequence $x_n$, not just *some* such sequence. “THERE EXISTS” only means you can find at least one sequence.

Comment: @ClementC. I agree with you. I edited my question. Could you give some help?

Comment: @MPW do you mean that I should find $x_n \in R$??

Comment: @SiHyunKim Sure. Use the mean value theorem.

Comment: I mean that you cannot conclude that $f$ is continuous at $c$ just because there exists a sequence $x_n\to c$ such that $f(x_n)\to f(c)$. To make that conclusion, you would have to know that $f(x_n)\to f(c)$ for EVERY sequence $x_n\to c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is flawed, as it goes by assuming that $f'$ is continuous at $c$ when you write:

> $$
> f'(c) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)
> $$
>   for (any) sequence $x_n)_n$ converging to $c$.

But $f'$ may *not* be continuous at $c$, that is the point.

To prove the statement (which is "there *exists* a sequence $(x_n)_n$," crucially not "for *every* sequence $(x_n)_n$" as the former would be equivalent to continuity of $f'$), you can use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). *(And note that the MVT asks only for differentiability, not that $f$ be continuously differentiable.)*

Indeed, by the MVT we have that for every $n\geq 1$, there exists $x_n \in (c, c+\frac{1}{n})$ such that
$$
f'(x_n) = \frac{f(c+\frac{1}{n})-f(c)}{\frac{1}{n}}\,.
$$
But now, by the very definition of $f'(c)$, we have
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$
so in particular 
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(c+\frac{1}{n})-f(c)}{\frac{1}{n}}\,.
$$

Answer (score 3):

For $f(x)=x^{2}\cos(1/x)$, $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=0$, then $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)$, and $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Still, $f'(x_{n})\rightarrow 0$ for $x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}$.